# Problems with Resolution/scaling

Tags: 14.04, resolution, scaling

First of all i am sorry if i'm being a noob but i kind of am....I've been searching the internet for help but couldn't find anything so here i am. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (updated+correrct drivers) on my HP Mini 210-2011sq and i am having a problem with scaling the windows. It makes Ubuntu kind of unusable since allot of buttons that need to be pressed go below the screen and i cant reach them. Standard resolution is 1024x600

I've added some pictures so you can get the idea. If i can help in any way with more info please do tell me.

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWwed.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aco3y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with `xrandr`.  Assuming your native resolution is 1366x768, you can emulate a larger screen by running the command

'xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1.50x1.50 --panning 2049x1152'

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am sorry for taking so long to respond.I tried your command in the terminal and now I can pan through the desktop using the cursor and see the buttons i didn't see before. I tried different combination and now i am at 1600x900 but i would like to have a FIXED desktop and not be needed to pan through it. Do you have any more ideas? I would like to correctly scale the windows to the desktop not run around on it :) Thank you very much for your answer again, i really apreciate it, and i look forward to hearing your ideeas

Comment: Do you know what the native resolution of your screen is?

Comment: Yes sorry for not mentioning that from the start.It's 1024x600

Comment: Modify the command to read `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --scale 1.50x1.50 --panning 1536x900`  The scale factor could be modified to get to 1600 in the horizontal by `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --scale 1.5625x1.50 --panning 1600x900`

Comment: Ok.I used the first command now the windows look like they should but now everything is extremely small (for example i cant make heads or tales for the battery percent or time). Should i try a lower resolution?

Comment: Either a lower resolution, or change the icon sizes.  Compiz Configuration Manager can do this (and also break your OS) or the Unity Tweak Tool

Comment: I used the "make text bigger" from Ubuntu universal access.Thanks man!It's perfect now!Is there a way to make this command run automatically at start-up or do i have to enter it manually again?

Comment: You could put it into `/etc/rc.local` or you could place it into a script, and cause the script to run at login.  [Startup Applications](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)